# Recording B2B Call Using UCMA 4.0 / Lync 2013

Tags: exchange-server, lync, ucma

I wrote an IVR Using UCMA 4.0, incoming call answered using UserEndpoint and the endpoint create a back to back call to callee.
I want to record this AVcall. What ca I do?
I read that I can create a conference and create b2b call from conference to caller and callee and Record Audio using ApplicationEndpoint but I want an example or simpler way.
Can I record all calls with Exchange if no please show me an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UCMA B2BCall's are media-less. i.e. the RTP stream goes directly between the source and destinations of the call.  UCMA can only record calls that are terminated at the UCMA application (basically non B2BCalls).  So UCMA B2BCall's are only in the signally path (sip) only.

This is why it's complex to record B2BCalls and is the reason why you have to turn the call into a conference call.  Then you can add a (hidden) participant into the conference that you can use to record it with.

You can look at the Microsoft UCMA reference application ContactCenter for
an example of the conferencing support and adding the hidden participant.
Once you have the hidden participant then using it to record is easy.